# Create a Jira Issue Using PHP and curl

Tags: php, curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I have recently started working with Jira and am trying to make a web based form on my customer client portal that will allow people to enter issues.

From my searching I have found the API examples Jira provides: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue

However this uses something alone these lines:

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data {see below} -H 
"Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/
```

However curl is something I have never used before. I have it configured in on my server to work (did a basic test to ensure it does). But I feel like this setup is not how it works for PHP.

Online I find it says to break the curl into parts like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

but I am very unsure how I would break that command into it... also unsure how I would receive the data it is supposed to return (From the sites example):

```
{
   "id":"39002",
   "key":"TEST-103",
    "self":"http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-103"
}
```

Any tips for going about creating an issue in PHP like this would be fantastic.

Comment: probably better to use library to handle requests e.g. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good SDKs to work with:

https://github.com/chobie/jira-api-restclient

https://github.com/lesstif/php-jira-rest-client

Then you have a lot of function and a clean structure to work with JIRA. The second one has more function.

**Login example:**

use JiraRestApi\Configuration\ArrayConfiguration;
use JiraRestApi\Issue\IssueService;

```
$iss = new IssueService(new ArrayConfiguration(
   array(
      'jiraHost' => 'https://your-jira.host.com',
      'jiraUser' => 'jira-username',
      'jiraPassword' => 'jira-password',
   )
));
```

Comment: I dont see in their examples where they set username or password... kinda unsure how it connects. https://github.com/lesstif/php-jira-rest-client/blob/master/tests/IssueTest.php and the function testCreateIssue() is what im looking for, but again don't see a way to authenticate or connect to Jira.

Comment: On the first page is an example... https://github.com/lesstif/php-jira-rest-client

Comment: Okay im just blind. Thank you